# Get row with latest date in group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group

I have  table with invoice actions. One invoice can have multiple actions. I need to create a view with one row for each invoice. And that row should be the latest action. I have currently following:

```
SELECT  tbl.*
FROM [dbo].[Tester] tbl JOIN
      (SELECT TransNo, MAX(TransDate) AS MxDt
       FROM [dbo].[Tester]
       GROUP BY TransNo
      ) sub
      ON tbl.TransNo = sub.TransNo AND TransDate = MxDt;
```

I have seen multiple posts in here stating this is the way to do it. However I get multiple rows in the result set with same TransNo? Have I missed something?

Data set:

[image]

Result running query:

[image]

I would expect to only have one row for each transaction. Even when it has two with same dates then it should just take one.

Comment: I don't understand how the data is being used at all.

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I have updated post. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend this approach but you need another condition in the `join`:

```
SELECT  tbl.TransNo
FROM [clm].[InvoiceView] tbl JOIN
      (SELECT TransNo, MAX(ActDate) AS MxDt
       FROM [clm].[InvoiceView]
       GROUP BY TransNo
      ) sub
      ON tbl.TransNo = sub.TransNo AND ActDate = MxDt;
```

I would instead recommend window functions:

```
select iv.*
from (select iv.*,
             row_number() over (partition by transno order by actdate desc) as seqnum
      from InvoiceView iv
     ) iv
where seqnum = 1;
```

or:

```
select iv.*
from InvoiceView iv
where iv.actdate = (select max(iv2.date)
                    from InvoiceView iv2
                    where iv2.transno = iv.transno
                   );
```

Comment: First one did not work. Still dublicates. And second one I stopped after the query has been running for 5 minutes.

Comment: Same with 3 still dublicates.

Comment: Can it be because there is multiple actions with same date and transno?

Comment: @ThomasSegato . . . `row_number()` cannot return duplicates for `transno` if that is the only partitioning key.  My guess is that you have `transo` values that *look* the same but are not the same.  This can occur if the value is a string and there are "hidden" or look-alike characters.  Or if the value is a *floating* point value and there are inexact values.

Answer (score 0):

For this query, you want another joining condition on the dates:

```
SELECT  tbl.TransNo
FROM [clm].[InvoiceView] tbl
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  TransNo, MAX(ActDate) AS [MxDt]
    FROM [clm].[InvoiceView]
    GROUP BY TransNo
) sub ON tbl.TransNo = sub.TransNo AND tbl.ActDate = sub.[MxDt]
                      -----------> here
```

However, there are other ways to do this, that I would recommend. One option is `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select iv.*, row_number() over(partition by transno order by actdate desc) rn
    from [clm].[InvoiceView] iv
) iv
where rn = 1
```

Comment: First one did not work. Still dublicates. And second one I stopped after the query has been running for 5 minutes.

Comment: Can it be because there is multiple actions with same date and transno?